# php associative array values always set?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
   $test['test'] = 'test';
   if(isset($test['test']['x']))
     return $test['test']['x'];
```

This statement returns the first character of the string in $test['test'] (in this case 't'), no matter what is specified as dimension 2.

I can't wrap my head around this behavior. I use isset() all the time. Please advise.

Comment: You are missing a closing bracket at the end of your if statement

Comment: i didn't make an open bracket :)

Comment: It's inadvisable to overuse `isset` *all the time*. PHP would have told you about the problem otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're not indexing an array, you're indexing a string. Strings are *not* arrays in PHP. They happen to share a concept of indexes with arrays, but are really character sequences even though there is no distinct char data type in PHP.

In this case, since strings are only indexed numerically, `'x'` is being converted into an integer, which results in 0. So PHP is looking for `$test['test'][0]`. Additionally `$test` is only a single-dimensional array, assuming `'test'` is the only key inside.

Not really relevant to your question, but if you try something like this you should get `'e'`, because when converting `'1x'` to an integer, PHP drops anything that isn't a digit and everything after it:

```
// This actually returns $test['test'][1]
return $test['test']['1x'];
```

---

If you're looking for a second dimension of the `$test` array, `$test['test']` itself needs to be an array. This will work as expected:

```
$test['test'] = array('x' => 'test');

if (isset($test['test']['x']))
    return $test['test']['x'];
```

Of course, if your array potentially contains `NULL` values, or you want to make sure you're checking an array, use `array_key_exists()` instead of `isset()` as sirlancelot suggests. It's sliiiiightly slower, but doesn't trip on `NULL` values or other indexable types such as strings and objects.

Comment: Damn, beat me by 60 seconds! :P

Comment: You should be careful when using string indices on purpose. This is not the case here, but i thought you should know (if you did not already). It can get really messy when dealing with multi-byte characters.

Comment: @Vilx-: Here's the secret: my answer started off as the first sentence :P

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists) for testing array keys.

It's returning `'t'` because all strings can be treated as arrays and `'x'` will evaluate to 0 which is the first letter/value in the variable.

Comment: Strings are not cast as arrays.

Comment: excellent, thanks, although it can't work in the above scenario because $test['test'] is a string. any idea why this behavior occurs?

Comment: @Orbit: What are you trying to find 'x' in - the string or the array?

Comment: `array_key_exists()` is slower, but `isset()` only works for testing array keys when you're sure none of the values are `NULL`. Choose either depending on your situation.

Comment: I'm not looking for x in the string 'test' , I'm looking to determine if I have set a value for it. I see my error now, if I want an arbitrary string and a sub dimension I have to set $test['test'] = array('abc').

Comment: $test['test'] = 'abc';
$test['test']['woot'] = "123";
print_r($test['test']['woot']); yields 1, makes sense per your description.